# pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed Error: when assigning map of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, dictionary, variable-assignment, smart-pointers

I'm trying to set a map of unique_ptr with a method.

```
class A {
    map<int, unique_ptr<B>> x;
public:
    void setx(const map<int, unique_ptr<B>>& x) {this->x = x;} // <-- error
    ...
};
```

However, I got this error.

```
'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<ContextSummary>]' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
```

What's wrong with this assignment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is non-copyable, therefore you can't copy a `std::map` that holds `unique_ptrs`. You can move it though:

```
void setx(map<int, unique_ptr<B>> x) {
    this->x = std::move(x);
}
```

Note that in order to move the map, you need it not to be a `const` reference, otherwise you can't move it. Taking it by value allows the caller to use either temporaries or moved lvalues.

So now, you'd use your code like this:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<B>> some_map = ...;
some_a.setx(std::move(some_map));
```

Or like this, using temporaries:

```
some_a.setx({
    {1, make_unique<B>(...)},
    {2, make_unique<B>(...)}
});
```

As pointed out by 0x499602D2, you can do this in your constructor directly:

```
A::A(map<int, unique_ptr<B>> x) 
: x(std::move(x)) {

}
```

Comment: Can't he use the mem-initializer list to do that?

Comment: @0x499602D2 do you mean instead of `setx`?

Comment: Yes, through a constructor that takes such a parameter.

Comment: @0x499602D2 of course, but that's not what OP is asking. I'll add an example though, thanks :P.